# How to convert to explicit join?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a sql statement I've created, and I need to transform it to use explict join operators so that all compare against constant clauses, and only compare against constant clauses, appear in the where clause for the query.

I am not sure how to make this change though, can anyone show me how I would do this?  Here is what I have:

```
select S.sname
from P, J, S, SPJ
where P.pname = 'Bolt'
and J.city = 'London'
and P.p# = SPJ.p#
and J.j# = SPJ.j#
and S.s# = SPJ.s#;
```

Comment: Dont forget to upvote if the post was helpful.  You have 40 upvotes a day, use them ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, you are looking to convert from sql89 syntax to an inner join.

It would look like this:

```
select
    S.sname
from
    P
    inner join SPJ on `P.p#` = `SPJ.p#` and P.pname = 'Bolt'
    inner join J on `SPJ.j#` = `J.j#` and J.city = 'London'
    inner join S on `SPJ.s#` = `S.s#`
```

I have added the `pname` and `city` restrictions to the join syntax because that appears to be what you asked for.  These can be left in the where clause as well however.

Also note that [extended or special characters in column names in mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html) (like `p#`) must be enclosed in backticks.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM P INNER JOIN SPJ ON P.p#=SPJ.p#
   INNER JOIN J ON J.j# = SPJ.j#
   INNER JOIN S ON S.s# = SPJ.s#
WHERE P.pname = 'Bolt'
AND J.city = 'London';
```

The conditions that are used to combine tables are placed in the `JOIN` clauses, and the other conditions are left in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I like to upvote competing answers and yours is a good one.  Plus there's a badge for it. :) +1